# How can SQL Server use more than 4 cores?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I've just noticed that our SQL Server is only using 4/8 cores. We have quantity 4 x 2 core licenses through VLSC. I assume that means we should have 8 cores available.

How can SQL Server use all 8 cores?

Comment: how did you found out that SQL server is only using this number of cores? as i also need to find it out myself, i cannot find any way to do it

Comment: Stretching my memory here, but I'm pretty sure it was just using the performance tab in task manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28928439/SQL-2014-server-only-using-4-logical-processors-based-on-SQL-Server-Licensing-when-6-logical-processors-are-available.html).

Basically SQL Server can only detect 4 sockets. Our VM environment was configured as 8 sockets with 1 core each, so SQL could only use 4 cores because it could only use 4 sockets. After reconfiguring the VM to use 2 sockets with 4 cores each (mirroring our physical hardware), it was able to use all 8 cores. Hopefully this helps someone else along the way.